# React usestate is not updating even after using useeffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux, use-state

I am using usestate, but it not updating even if i am using useeffect. i wanted to show grid once call to backend is complete

```
const backendData: any = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.backendData);  
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
const [data, setBackendData] = useState(backendData);

//once call to backend is complete, backendData gets updated
useEffect(() => {
  setBackendData(backendData);
  setIsLoading(false);
}, [backendData]);

useEffect(() => { 
  setIsLoading(isLoading);
}, [isLoading]);

const onSearchButtonClick = () => { 
  setIsLoading(true); //when i set isloading to true it is not updating even if i have useeffect 
  //call to backend
  getSearchDetails();
  if (!isLoading) { //i wanted to show grid once call to backend is complete 
  //but this is always false and grid is displaying before call to backend is complete
    setGridShow(true);       
  }
};
```

Comment: Have you tried doing `console.log(backendData)` I think it's not being updated and therefore since it's inside the dependency array `useEffect` is not being called again. Also, you don't need to make use of `useEffect` when using `useSelector`. The component will rerender whenever the selector is updated.

Comment: my problem is here if(!isLoading){ 
    setGridShow(true);       
} even though isLoading is set to true, it is not updating and the grid is showing before call to backend is complete

Comment: can't help much more if you only share partially your component.

Comment: `useEffect(() => { 
  setIsLoading(isLoading);
}, [isLoading]);` is an infinite loop, and pointless.